# API insightvm powershell script fails

Tags: json, powershell, api

I have the following script, which is used to create a static asset group in InsightVM, based on the following filters:

- computer name starts with C1
- hosts not in asset groups:179,198,200

Same first part of the code, regarding PUT is used in other API calls and it does not fail, hence I am assuming I am doing something wrong with the body.

The code was generated with Insomnia or Postman(written in json) and saved as powershell script to be allow me to run the API call from a windows device.

This is the start of the script, which fails.

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic usernamehere=")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
#establishes TLS version; without it, the script fails on TLS errors.
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

#sends the body of the request; creates the site name and description, as well as time interval
$body = "{
`n    `"description`": `"Workstations not in PCI.`",
`n    `"name`": `"Workstations_Not_In_PCI`",
`n    `"searchCriteria`": {
`n        `"filters`": [
`n            {
`n                `"field`": `"asset-name`",
`n                `"operator`": `"starts-with`",
`n                `"value`": C1,
`n                `"values`": [
`n                    `"string`"
`n                ]
`n            },
`n            
`n            {
`n                `"field`" : `"site-id`",
`n                `"operator`" : `"not-in`",
`n                `value`" : 179,198,200
`n                `"values`" : [
`n                    `"string`"        
`n               ]
`n
`n        ],
`n        `"match`": `"all`"
`n    },
`n    `"type`": `"static`"
`n                        },
`n     }"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://insightcon.ds.city.vancouver.bc.ca:3780/api/3/asset_groups" -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

**This is the error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdLFE.jpg)

Comment: The json you produce using that strange code is invalid. Use a [Here-String](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) so you don't have to use those horrible backticks all over (which is part of the json being invalid).

Comment: A here-string will also allow you to ditch the newlines.  You may also want to check the documentation, It might be easier to use a hash table